# rails production mode asset_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

trying to figure out how to link to a template using angularjs ui-router... but in production mode... so I'm trying to fingerprint this file?  Not sure how to do this:

```
  $stateProvider

  .state('app' ,
    url: '/'
    templateUrl: '<%=asset_url('cat_index.html.slim')%>'
    controller: 'CatsController'
  )
```

If I just put

```
templateUrl: '/assets/cat_index.html.slim'
```

the link doesn't work....and the browser gives me a 404 error when it tries to find the file.

EDIT:  However.. if I put

`templateUrl: '/assets/cat_index-b385a5578afa6eff68aa5a5f76da4133.html'`

It works... but it seems like there should be a method in rails to generate the right url...kind of the same way you have to use get_asset_uri for images?  idk

Here's my config production file.  I DONT want to compile on the fly... I want to precompile and then use the static public files with the fingerprints:

```
Writersarah::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  config.assets.compress = true


  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Template files don't get fingerprints, only assets (img, css, js)

Comment: my main goal is to precompile and not have to 'lazy compile' or compile on the fly.  I can't seem to do this... because the links to the static html files are tucked into the javascript file of the ui router... this is similar to how you have to use a get_link sort of method to properly locate images... which will have thumbprints on them after the precompile.